# Explicit casting to uint when there is no such operator

Tags: c#

I have written a simple wrapper around a `ulong` with a private data member. I want to be able to cast the wrapper to `ulong` to retrieve the data. I want it to be illegal to cast to `uint` and lose data, so I did not write an explicit cast to `uint`. You can imagine my surprise when C# allowed me to cast to `uint` without complaint and did not throw an exception even though the high bits were lost.

Here is my test code:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ULongWrapper a = new ULongWrapper(0xfffffffffUL);
        ulong b = (ulong)a;
        uint c = (uint)a;
        Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", b);
        Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", c);
    }
}
class ULongWrapper {
    private ulong data;
    public ULongWrapper(ulong data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public static explicit operator ulong(ULongWrapper x) {
        return x.data;
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
fffffffff
ffffffff
```

This seems like unwanted behavior, since I want casts to `uint` to fail at compile time! The compiler is using the `ulong` explicit cast operator and then somehow implicitly casting that result to a `uint` without bounds checking. Is this a bug in C#, and if not, why?

Comment: `int d = (int)a` produces error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'TestProgram.ULongWrapper' to 'int'. However, `int d = (int)b` works.

Comment: How about defining an explicit conversion from your class to uint, and throwing an exception in the conversion method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is this a bug in C#?

No.

> Why not?

Because the behaviour demonstrated here is consistent with the specification. Carefully read sections 6.4.4 and 6.4.5 of the specification.  (Note that there are numerous ways in which the C# compiler is not consistent with this section of the specification; the implementation has a number of bugs in obscure corner cases, particularly involving lifted operators.)

> I want it to be illegal to cast to uint and lose data.

You can't always get what you want, unfortunately.

> You can imagine my surprise when C# allowed me to cast to uint without complaint and did not throw an exception even though the high bits were lost.

This is a bit surprising, I agree.

The rule is: every user-defined conversion is allowed to have a *standard conversion* inserted on both the *input* and the *output*. Moreover, if it is an *explicit conversion* -- that is, you are doing a cast -- then the standard conversions inserted may be either implicit *or explicit* standard conversions. (And in fact, a cast may cause explicit standard conversions to be inserted into a user-defined implicit conversion!)

In your case there is an explicit user-defined conversion from ULongWrapper to ulong, and a standard explicit conversion from ulong to uint. Therefore it is legal to cast ULongWrapper to uint.

You might consider not implementing an explicit conversion in the first place, since apparently you don't like the semantics of explicit conversions. Just write a method or property that returns the underlying ulong, and be done with it.

Comment: +1, much better than my round about explanation in my comments.

Comment: Then why can't I do `int d = (int)a` (produces error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'TestProgram.ULongWrapper' to 'int')?

Comment: @Zach: Good catch. You have discovered one of the weirdest rules in C#. The rule is: a standard *explicit* conversion must be a *backwards* standard *implicit* conversion. Since there is no *implicit conversion* from int to ulong (because the int might be negative) and no *implicit conversion* from ulong to int (because of the range), the explicit conversion from ulong to int is *non-standard*! I find this rule *crazy* but nevertheless it is a rule of C#.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit conversion exists between `uint` and `ulong`.  You allow a conversion to `ulong`, and you *explicitly* cast to `uint`.  What do you expect?  You are telling the compiler "don't worry about it, I know what I am doing".

> and then somehow implicitly casting that result to a uint

There's nothing implicit about it.  You are performing a cast.  This seems like overly-defensive programming to me.

Comment: I don't allow an implicit conversion to `ulong`, though. An actually explicit conversion chain would be `(uint)(ulong)a`, which should (and does) truncate without complaint.

Comment: @Zach: I realize why that may seem confusing, but the compiler can see that you have defined an explicit conversion to `ulong`.  Well, if it can convert to `ulong`, and an explicit conversion to `uint` is valid, then the entire expression is valid.  So, in effect, you *do* allow for it.

Answer (score 1):

An overflow happens during the cast, but overflow checking is "opt in" in C#.
Wrap the casts in:

```
checked 
{
  ..
}
```

So its really "by design" rather than a bug. And returning a ulong will always be castable at compile time I think.

Comment: Still, this is a runtime check, not a compile time check.  Not that I know of a solution... just saying.

Comment: `checked{
        public static explicit operator ulong(ULongWrapper x) {
            return x.data;
        }}`

Results in CS1519: Invalid token 'checked' in class, struct, or interface member declaration.

Comment: Also, as Ed says, this checks at runtime, and is no more effective than `public static explicit operator uint(ULongWrapper x) { throw new OverflowException();}`

Comment: @Zack that fails to compile "Invalid token 'checked' in class, struct, or interface member declaration"

Comment: @Zach: You don't put the block around the entire method (you put it around the cast), but again, this is not what you are after.  Sometimes there is no compile time solution (not claiming that, I just don't see one).  Sometimes people can use your code the wrong way and that's just how it is.  I do think this is overly defensive and unnecessary.